# Rails 3 Ajax Search

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following the railscasts rails ajax tutorial and geting into some trouble, am i missing something or is the tutorial only meant to be covered for pre rails 3.1?

controller:

```
def index

    @notes = Note.search(params[:search])


end
```

Model:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.search(search)
      if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
      else
        scoped
      end
    end


end
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag notes_path, :method => 'get', :id => "notes_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <div id="notes"><%= render 'notes' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Coffescript file:

```
jQuery ->
  # Ajax sorting and pagination on click
  $('#notes td.sortable a, #notes .pagination a').live('click', ->
    $.getScript(this.href)
    false
  )
  # Ajax search on submit
  $('#notes_search').submit( ->
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script')
    false
  )
  # Ajax search on keyup
  $('#products_search input').keyup( ->
    $.get($("#notes_search").attr("action"), $("#notes_search").serialize(), null, 'script')
    false
  )
```

Error is on this line:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Notes#index

   <div id="notes"><%= render 'notes' %></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionView::MissingTemplate` exception basically says that there is no view file for the action you're trying to render.

You need to have a partial view called "_notes.html.erb" for it to work. Inside the view you should have something like that:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
<%= will_paginate @notes %>
```

I took that code from the tutorial you're referring to http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax, maybe you don't have those params or don't have will_paginate gem installed yet, adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but it still doesn't work, just getting another list of notes on the page.

Comment: At what point do you get that error? On page load or after the search is done?

Comment: Upon page load. am i missing a return argument in my controller? possibly a return JSON?

Comment: No. The cause of the error is `render 'notes'` operator. It basically says it to render action `notes`, you don't have that.

Comment: they have this in a products.js.erb file?? $("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("products")) %>"); was this pre 3.1?

Comment: please send me a link to the example you are referring to. They probably also have a view called `products`.

Answer (score 1):

This totally irrelevant to the tutorial but why don't you consider using  [datatables](http://datatables.net/). Does the same thing as the railscasts tutorial and also has full documentation and API to make it fully customizable.

Comment: I'm not really after table searching, i just need to learn ajax searching.