# Rails Ajax search not doing anything -- 404 error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Trying to figure out Ajax search in a Rails 3 app, following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908566/rails-3-ajax-search), which itself borrows from a Railscast. Currently, when I submit, nothing happens, and if I go into the Chrome console, I see this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&_=1361491523102 404 (Not Found)
```

posts.js line 5 seems to be culpable, but that just seems to be the jQuery call, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My relevant code:

**posts.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
    # Ajax search on submit
    $('.search_form').submit( ->
        $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script')
        false
  )
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @search = Post.search(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { redirect_to @post }
  end
end

def search
  @search = Post.search(params[:search])
  render json: { results: @search }
end
```

**post.rb**

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: "get", class: "search_form form-inline",
 style: "display:inline-block;" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search:", id: "search_field" %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search", name: nil, class: "btn search", remote: true) %>
<% end %>

# Testing for @search stops it from pulling a "no method '.first' for nil NilClass" error.
<div id="list"><%= render partial: 'list', locals: { search: @search } if @search%></div>
```

**list.html.erb**

```
<ul>
    <% @search.each do |p| %>
        <li><a href=<%= p.id %> ><%= p.name %> <span class="manual_small">(<%= p.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>)</span></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?

EDIT -- Adding relevant lines of routes file:

```
resources :posts

# ...

match '/search', to: 'posts#search'
```

I already had that '/search' route there. Is that right -- in which case, is the problem somewhere else? Does the rest of the code look goodish?

EDIT -- added search method to PostsController, per Damien's rec. New things of interest are a) the way I call the partial, the new search action, and that fact that then I tried to replace the contents of the show method in Post.rb with "Post.all", it still didn't show anything. No errors thrown, though.

Comment: you most probably dont have a route that handles `/search`.  show us your routes file

Comment: Thanks! Added it above. There's a lot more going on in the file, but I just put the lines that have anything to do with Post. If you want, I can put all of it.

Comment: can you add the `search` action content?

Comment: No search action! Didn't realize I needed one. What should be in it? When I tried an earlier version of this without AJAX, I had a search action that was basically a replica of show (+ @search etc), with all the same variables, otherwise it wouldn't work, because it rendered the show page. Is that the right idea? It seemed very unDRY

Comment: Sorry, just checked over your post more thoroughly. With AJAX, you shouldn't need to render the entire `show` page, just return the searched results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "No search action! Didn't realize I needed one. What should be in it?
>   When I tried an earlier version of this without AJAX, I had a search
>   action that was basically a replica of show (+ @search etc), with all
>   the same variables, otherwise it wouldn't work, because it rendered
>   the show page. Is that the right idea? It seemed very unDRY"

Using AJAX, there is no need to render the entire `show` page. Just return the filtered results in desired format:

```
def search
  @search = Post.search(params[:search])
  render json: { results: @search }
end
```

Add format based returns if necessary.

Comment: Hmm. So I did that, (all my new code is now above), and though it isn't erroring, it doesn't do anything. Suspecting my search method, which I borrowed, I replaced it with just Post.all, and searching still doesn't do anything. Am I maybe using that method wrong? I don't know what the self.method(argument) structure is about.